# How do you apply shader on CCRenderTexture twice?

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-iphone, glsl, shader, cocos2d-x

I managed to apply blur shader on my CCRenderTexture. But it only works for single-pass shader (in my case only for 1 direction).

```
/* ... after initializing CCGLProgram ... */
renderTexture->getSprite()->setShaderProgram( shader );
renderTexture->begin();
parallaxNode->visit();
renderTexture->end();
```

In this case my program will draw the horizontally blurred image, the image itself is a composite made from the parallax node. 
However if I were to apply vertical blur shader on the same CCRenderTexture object again, it will ignore the previous applied shader, thus my image would end up with only vertical blurring.

Retrieving the CCTexture from the renderTexture right after the begin - end block, e.g:

```
renderTexture->begin();
parallaxNode->visit();
renderTexture->end();
CCTexture2D * texture = renderTexture->getSprite()->getTexture();
CCSprite * sprite = CCSprite::createWithTexture( texture );
```

shows that the sprite is still the image before the shader applied on it.

So, how does one approach this ? When and how can I retrieve the texture that already has shader applied on it from the CCRenderTexture ?

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Write a shader that combines horizontal and vertical blurring.

Comment: Hmmm, does it mean that there's no way to do that using CCRenderTexture ? Since later on I want to try to combine with other kind of shaders too.

Comment: As the texture is rendered its shader runs once. You could render the sprite to a RT, then use that RT in another RT with a different shader. But that's not going to be fast. Shaders are meant to do all filtering in one pass. If you want to combine multiple effects you need a shader that combines the algorithms. At least on mobile devices.